# Find all real $x$ ,such $8x^3-20$ and $2x^5-2$ is perfect square

Tags: number-theory

> Find all real numbers $x$,such 
>   $$8x^3-20,2x^5-2$$  is  the perfect square of an integer

My idea: First we find the real number $x$ such $$8x^3-20,2x^5-2$$ is postive integer numbers,and second the real numbers such
$$8x^3-20=m^2,2x^5-2=n^5$$

How prove this all real numbers?

Comment: Do you mean the perfect square of an integer?

Comment: Yes,@MarkBennet

Comment: Are you really offering a bounty for a problem whose solution is in the comments?

Comment: @math110-Look,as per Robert Israel's comment-though 486-2=484 is a perfect square,but -486-2=-488 is not a perfect square,similarly neither 21932 nor (-21972) are perfect squares,and neither 1075646 nor (-1075650) are perfect fifth powers

Answer (score 3):

First observe that $x$ is a positive integer. $x^5$ and $x^3$ are rationals; then $x=(x^3)^2/x^5$ is rational; finally $(2x)^5$ is an even positive integer so $2x$ must be an even positive integer.

In order to find a bound for $x$, consider the product of $8x^3−20=m^2$ and $2x^5−2=n^2$ and complete the square.
\begin{align*}
(mn)^2 &= (8x^3-20)(2x^5-2) \\ 
&= 16x^8 - 40x^5 - 16x^3 + 40 \\
&= (4x^4-5x)^2 -(16x^3+25x^2-40) \\
&= (4x^4-5x-1)^2 +(8x^4-16x^3-25x^2-10x+39).
\end{align*}
If $x\ge4$ then the remaining terms
$16x^3+25x^2-40$ and $8x^4-16x^3-25x^2-10x+39$ are positive and we find
$$
4x^4-5x-1 < mn < 4x^4-5x
$$
that is impossible. Hence, $x\le3$.

For $x=1$ we have $8x^3-20<0$, no solution.

For $x=2$ we have $8x^3-20=44$, no solution.

For $x=3$ we have $8x^3-20=14^2$ and $2x^5-2=22^2$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**.  If we have
$$8x^3-20=m^2\ ,\quad 2x^5-2=n^2$$
then
$$x^3=\frac{m^2+20}{8}\ ,\quad x^5=\frac{n^2+2}{2}\ .$$
Can you see how to obtain $x$ from these two equations?

Comment: $$\left(\dfrac{m^2+20}{8}\right)^5=\left(\dfrac{n^2+2}{2}\right)^3$$?,then How solve this eqution?

Comment: e.g. $m = \pm 14$, $n = \pm 22$.

Comment: @math110 You don't want to solve the equation in your last comment.  You are trying to find $x$ but you have just eliminated it entirely!

Comment: But you don't have solutions for $x$ unless that equation in $m$ and $n$ is satisfied.

Comment: BTW these are the only solutions with $|m| \le 10000$.

Comment: Plugging f:=EllipticCurve([0,-20]); followed by IntegralPoints(f); into Magma ensures that the solution Robert found is the only one (i.e. $x=3$).

Comment: @RobertIsrael fair enough, I missed that.